# Is tap water an ohmic conductor?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, water, electrochemistry

Earlier today, I asked a question regarding why I was getting weird resistance readings and based on responses which I am thankful for concluded it could possibly be the electrolysis, the fact i calculated resistance through current and voltage, or both. However I have a further question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-3M3r69pOQ&t=224s

In this experiment someone tested AC through water (and also did DC in another video) and the results other than the early voltages (which lends credence to my theory about it being calculations) is quite linear and approximately ohmic. I did calculations and got these results.

[image]

Does this mean water is mostly ohmic and if the probes were close together would it be the same level of ohmicness?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487606/is-ohms-law-valid-for-water#:~:text=The%20Ohm%20law%20is%20approximately,and%20DC%20current%20are%20applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have empirical data for your water. Good job! This is better than any analytical model. Your data tells you that for a certain span of voltage, $V \propto I$. By definition, your water is Ohmic in this span.