# What causes water to be non-ohmic?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, water, electrochemistry

Its been a while since I posted here about what I have been trying to find out regarding resistance of water at high voltages. I may seem oddly obsessed with this, but it is forming a big part of a science project I am doing revolving around electrical safety with water and wet things, using detailed resistance values to back things up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-3M3r69pOQ&t=332s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF9DCNkaE8I&t=335s

I've linked these videos before, but I have since studied them a fair bit more and calculated resistance values at different voltages as per the video with AC. Here is what I found;

| Voltage (V) | Resistance (ohms) |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 17000 |
| 49.8 | 171724 |
| 100 | 166666 |
| 150 | 166666 |
| 200 | 166666 |
| 225 | 164306 |
| 250 | 163265 |
| 287 | 163068 |

So for this I have come to the conclusion that whilst it doesn't quite follow ohms law, the resistance does not decrease by much at all (in the end only by like 8,000 ohms). My question is what would normally happen that it only strays from ohms law by a little bit, and what is the reason it strays from it but not by much? Also why does resistance remain at the same value for a bit? And would increased salts or any other substance in the water affect how much it deviates from ohms law?

Hope I have made the question clear and understandable :D

Comment: What electrodes are you using?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487606/is-ohms-law-valid-for-water#:~:text=The%20Ohm%20law%20is%20approximately,and%20DC%20current%20are%20applied

Comment: @Chemomechanics Its not me doing the experiment as I said its from a video but the guy attached wires to the metal/copper ends of a pipe

Comment: @SteveSaban So basically that proves what I said about it being approximately but not quite ohmic? Been questioning this due to some saying its not ohmic

Comment: Nothing is perfectly ohmic, but all stable materials approximately are for sufficiently small ranges.

Comment: @effectivedragon Technically, water is not a conductor so there is no reason for water to obey Ohms law. The ions in solution are the charge carriers and if the ion concentration (by addition of a salt or electrolyte) is high enough, the current will obey ohms law provided there is no other electrochemistry occurring at the electrode.

Comment: @SteveSaban So more salt means more ohmicness?

Comment: @effectivedragon The IV curve would be linear for a small voltage range  and the solution would have higher conductivity. As Chemomechanics mentioned, the range is limited by the hydrolysis of water and the redox potentials of the electrodes.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Is water a stable material as suggested for this as it does not deviate much

Comment: @effectivedragon “Stable” in this context simply means close to equilibrium—i.e., not superheated or supersaturated or anything where the state would evolve dramatically and independently upon an infinitesimal perturbation.

Comment: @effectivedragon The experiments in the video are not using a three electrode potentiostat configuration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiostat  Any IV measurement not using a poteniostat is not reliable especially high voltages.

Comment: @SteveSaban Arent potentiostats used to counter changes to resistance? Its the changes to resistance at high voltages I want to find out (as this thing I am doing is about electrical safety)

Comment: @effectivedragon. No. it is to provide a stable voltage measurement using a reference electrode. All the current is measured through two counter electrodes while the voltage is measure wrt a reference electrode with minimum current. For your application it may not be necessary but I did want you to be aware.

Comment: @SteveSaban Without a potentiostat is it a reliable way of monitoring resistance change?

Answer (score 2):

Water is non-ohmic because when the voltage applied across the electrodes in the water (in order to create a current flow and thereby allow a resistance to be calculated) reaches a certain value, the water molecules begin dissociating into ions which contribute to the electrical conductivity of the bulk water.

Comment: The thing is in this experiment cited rather than reaching a value and dipping the resistance kinda gradually goes down and not by much... seems theres a limit to how much the resistance decreases